# how to rename a folder in vbs script

Tags: vbscript

I am trying achieve renaming outlook folder around 100+ windows 10 client using below vbs script and nothing happening except (Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement) . Can someone please help me figure out where i am wrong.

```
'Check if a folder exists

Dim folderPath As String
folderPath = "C:\Users\sas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook-old"

If Dir(folderPath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then

    Debug.Print folderPath & " exists."

Else

    'Rename folder
Name "C:\Users\sas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" As "C:\Users\hmohamadmoosa\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook-old"

End If
```

Comment: *where i am wrong* `Name` statement is absent in VBScript syntax. [Statements (VBScript)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//7aw9cadb%28v%3dvs.85%29). Use FileSystemObject, [MoveFolder Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//465s5y8s%28v%3dvs.85%29) or [Move Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//465s5y8s%28v%3dvs.85%29) of Folder object.

Comment: Are you confined to  **VBScript**?? Why not **PowerShell**? `$FolderPath = 'c:\...\Outlook'`↵`Get-Item $FolderPath -Force | Rename-Item -NewName 'Outlook-old'-Force` or, more generally, `...-NewName {$_.Name + '-old'}...` which allows for pipeline input.

Comment: In my case i want script to search folder C:/user/outlook/Outlook-old if folder exists quit or rename c:/user/outlook/Outlook to outlook-old    Is that possible to achieve with power shell..?

Comment: You code is NOT vbscript. Here's the help file http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe